# Right Align Table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

This code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ca86D/
Generates:

```
a | b | c | d
```

How can I make it generate :

```
d | c | b | a
```

?

**Without changing the order of the < th >**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `dir="rtl"` attribute to table:

```
<table border="1" dir="rtl">
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/74XHk/1/

(tried to add it to `tr`, that didn't work)

Comment: `dir`, or `direction:` is used to handle the bidirectionality phenomenon http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#direction

Answer (score 4):

add in your css `th {float:right}`. This will reverse the sequence, because will start with first `th` which contains `d` and will float it at right, then the second and so on.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ca86D/2/

Answer (score 0):

Surely just

```
<table border="1">
     <tr>         
         <th>d</th>
         <th>c</th>
         <th>b</th>
         <th>a</th>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Hope I didn't misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>d</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>a</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```